# Is it possible to find the autocorrection text of UITextField is in OPEN/CLOSE state in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios8

I am enabling the autocorrection option of UITextField to show the suggestion text. Here my proble is want to identify the suggestion text view is in OPEN state or CLOSE state.

[image]

or

[image]

Please any one give me an idea about this.

Comment: please check https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITextAutocorrectionType

Comment: @WaseemShah how can i find that is in open/closed ?

Comment: simply like this  NSLog(@"txtField_Email = %d",txtField_Email.autocorrectionType);
it will give you autocorrectionType in integer

Comment: that i know.. i want to know when the user interaction with open/close state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can detect this change using keyboard height change notification as follows,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didReceiveKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                               object:nil];


- (void)didReceiveKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

        CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

        if (CGRectIsNull(keyboardEndFrame)) {
            return;
        }

        UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        NSInteger animationCurveOption = (animationCurve << 16);

        double animationDuration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                              delay:0.0
                            options:animationCurveOption
                         animations:^{


                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                         }];
}
```